# Which is better, One Jenkinsfile for similar pipelines or exclusive Jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a bunch of maven projects to be built and deployed to Nexus, we are upgrading from Jenkins 1.500 to latest version this opens pipeline possibilities for us. After good amount of research we wrote a single pipeline script that would query our bitbucket instance to find project key and repo so this script can be reused.

Stages involved: Checkout, Build, Test & Nexus Deploy

*Checkout stage involves different git repo, after that steps are the same*

Now we have this design, so similar projects uses same Jenkinsfile, is this correct?

As per current design `Jenkinsfile` under maven_nexus repo of Pipeline project (bitbucket structure) will be used for at least 400 projects. We find this as advantage since,

- Developers will not have to think about Jenkinsfile (We aren't into DevOps yet)
- Jenkins job creation can be automated with template file

Is there any disadvantage? are we doing something wrong by querying bitbucket instance from Jenkins pipeline script for every build? (though time/network cost is low, I'm not sure if this is the way to go).

So far in forums, I have read that project teams maintain their own Jenkinsfile. Is there good reason to give teams permission to edit at their will.

Comment: This is not really going to be possible to give a good answer to without a deep dive into the projects.

Comment: If not a good answer, a suggestion or best practice to follow will help me a lot. thanks for the interest. btw editing the question to add some more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no inherent "disadvantage" outside of a lack of customizable behavior. My instinct is to tell you to look into writing a Shared Library (described here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). This will let you store your "Checkout, Build, Test & Nexus Deploy" stages in one script that they can call, but they could also add their own work if they wanted something like linting, static analysis, or other custom behavior that you don't normally include. Specifically, look at the section called "Defining a more structured DSL". They give the following example (once you've setup your shared library):

Shared Library Step Definition:

```
// vars/buildPlugin.groovy
def call(body) {
    // evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()

    // now build, based on the configuration provided
    node {
        git url: "https://github.com/jenkinsci/${config.name}-plugin.git"
        sh "mvn install"
        mail to: "...", subject: "${config.name} plugin build", body: "..."
    }
}
```

Corresponding Jenkinsfile:

```
buildPlugin {
    name = 'git'
}
```

So, if your teams were using this pattern, they could add to that by doing something like...

```
node() {
    stage('Lint') {
        sh 'exit 0'
    }
}

buildPlugin {
    name = 'git'
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, I'l try to induct the approach and see if suits us

Comment: Trying to add Shared library, Jenkins > Configure System > Global Pipeline Libraries. But I can't specify where the script resides, i.e., Not able to give "Retrieval method"